# can chipset or sata version keep hard disk testing tool from recognizing the drive?

Tags: hard-drive, testdisk

I've a brand-new barracuda 500GB sata3 drive [ST500DM002](http://www.seagate.com/internal-hard-drives/desktop-hard-drives/barracuda/?sku=ST500DM002), installed on a [asrock B75M-DGS](http://www.asrock.com/mb/overview.us.asp?Model=B75M-DGS), and I'd like to test it's healt status, before starting using it.

When I launch seatools for dos, the program doesn't recognized the disk at all, so I try installing an OS on the drive, and everything seems to work well, so I think the disk it's ok.

Does somebody know, why this happen ? Can it be due to a chipset not supported from seatools for dos, or to the sata3, that is not completely supported from the actual version of seatools?

Any ideas is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: when you say dos, do you really mean DOS or are you just referring to a command-line environment of some kind? Real DOS would not possess the drivers to address a SATA bus at all, let alone SATA3.

Comment: I'm referring to real DOS but didn't know the it can't manage sata drive, changing AHCI with IDE, the test start correctly, as I reach 15 points I'll point you up!

Comment: @FrankThomas - The "dos" is probably FreeDOS, the "operating system" that the Seagate disk utility uses.  Retail HDD packages (at least Seagate and WD) include a utilities CD that can execute on x86 hardware. To avoid a chicken versus egg problem since the new HDD and/or PC may have no OS installed yet, these utilities are on a bootable CD that typically use FreeDOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hook the drive to a port that can be put into something to the effect of "Legacy" "IDE" mode.

This is (usually) changeable within the motherboard's BIOS.

Basically, no AHCI, no RAID, no Enhanced SATA controller options, as these would require additional drivers that the Seatools disk isn't going to contain, and probably couldn't support since (if memory serves) it *does* use standard DOS (DR-DOS I think).

Comment: you're my hero !! As I reach 15 points I'll point you up. thanks

Comment: as promised I've pointed you up :), bye